# Laravel different FormRequest conditioned by querystring

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-formrequest

In some methods of a controller I would like to be able to use different FormRequest depending on a value in the querystring, for example:

```
// always using the same route, only qs change

// different methods

?q=a -> methodA(ARequest $req)
?q=b -> methodB(BRequest $req)

// same method using an interface but different formrequest instance?

?q=a -> method(IRequest $req) // ARequest instance
?q=b -> method(IRequest $req) // BRequest instance
```

At the moment I have seen that I can use `make()` in the method to instantiate the class explicitly (and perform validation), or that I can override `callAction()` to call different methods depending on the querystring (but in this case the Request is already instantiated, argument binding does not work).

Is there any cleaner way?

**edit**

I couldn't use contextual binding (not sure there is no way, but haven't found one), on the other hand I realized that in `callAction()` I just needed to replace `$parameters` (which in my case normally only receives Request in an array) with the desired FormRequest, example:

```php
    public function callAction($method, $parameters)
    {
        $query = request()->query('q', null);
        if (!is_null($query)) {
            $query = Str::ucfirst($query);
            if (method_exists($this, $method . $query)) {
                $method .= $query;
                $parameters = [ resolve("App\\Http\\Requests\\Ajax\\${query}Request") ];
            }
        }
        return $this->{$method}(...array_values($parameters));
    }
```

I'll be using this version for now but I'm still interested to know if there is a cleaner way.

Comment: U may define rules depending on request params

Comment: But you may try to use contextual binding in service container https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/container#contextual-binding

Comment: @SiZE Thanks I missed ctx binding, it looks interesting and promising, I look into it